# What is the maximum number of skills that can be created for Skill-Based Routing?

Tags: limits, servicecloud, omnichannel, skill-based-routing

I cannot find it anywhere in [Salesforce Help Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_skills_based_routing.htm&type=5). The only information, when it comes to limitations, is regarding searching for already created skills (from [Create Skills for Skill-Based Routing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_skills_based_routing_create_skills.htm&type=5)):

> When agents search for skills, the search process looks for matching skills within only the first 2,000 skills. If more than 2,000 skills are set up, then the search results show matching skills from only the first 2,000 skills that were created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is presumably no maximum. If there were, it would be listed in the documentation. The 2000 limit simply refers to the search engine limit. You should be able to set up as many skills as you like, but having many thousands of skills will likely be less useful for skill-based routing.